# Ehcache to refresh when an update take place in a database

Tags: caching, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-4, spring-restcontroller

I am new to Ehcache, My Rest API cache works

```
<cache name="com.a.b.c.model.Act"
maxElementsInMemory="10000" overflowToDisk="false" statistics="true" />
```

If I do any update in Database through query, the cache won't update those changes.

If I do update through REST API the cache will get refreshed.

What change I have to make if I have to get cache refresh when a change happens in Database

Is it good to go with timeToLiveSeconds or any other configurations can be done?

Answer (score 5):

Updating the cache when the underlying system of record changes, and not through the service methods on which caching is performed, is the classical problem with caching.

Ehcache does not provide an out of the box solution there as it would mean supporting *ALL* the technologies that can act as a system of record. Not only databases but also web services and really anything a programmer can come up with.

However, if your application can live with having outdated data in cache for a small period of time, then *expiry* can be helpful. It effectively mark cache entries as valid for a period of time - time to live.

If your application cannot support stale data in cache, you will have to make sure the process to update the system of record takes care of invalidating the cache as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the code that is upadating the database can access Ehcache manager (same VM or distributed persistence) the best solution is to break the cache

```
CacheManager.getInstance().getEhcache("mycache").remove(key);
```

and let the cache refresh autonomously.

If you already dispose of the updated object you could also skip one step with `put`

```
CacheManager.getInstance().getEhcache("mycache").put(key, updatedObject);
```

If your code has `CacheEntryFactories` I would let the factory do the business (entry creation is centralized, you can add more logic there)